# Why is my cropped image little?

Tags: android, image, crop

I'm trying to do a code that allow the user to select a picture from gallery and crop it with an Intent to after all display it in a ImageView (For a profile picture purpose).

Everything is working well, the image cans be selected, it cans be cropped and display in an ImageView which is in a custom dialog. The thing is that the ImageView in my custom dialog is very little, even if I set wrap_content for width and height, so the user can hardly see the cropped image.

Here is a screenshot: [Little image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfnna.png)

**Code:**

my custom dialog (custom_dialog_pp.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/style_layout_rounded_white">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/useit_customdialog_pp_TV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/usethispic"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/style_tv_toproundcorner"/>

<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/profilpic"
    android:id="@+id/pp_customdialog_pp_IV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cancel_customdialog_pp_BTN"
        android:background="@drawable/style_button_primary"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/done_customdialog_pp_BTN"
        android:background="@drawable/style_button_primary"
        android:text="@string/done"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my MainActivity:

```
 ////////////////////
ChangeProfilPic.onClickListener {
 Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 2);
}
 ////////////////////

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 4 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap selectedImage = extras.getParcelable("data");


        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder mBuilderLoading = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        View mViewLoading = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_pp,null);

        final ImageView pp_customdialog_pp_IV = mViewLoading.findViewById(R.id.pp_customdialog_pp_IV);

        pp_customdialog_pp_IV.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);


        mBuilderLoading.setView(mViewLoading);
        final android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog dialogLoading = mBuilderLoading.create();
        dialogLoading.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialogLoading.show();


    } else if(requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        ImageCropFunction(data.getData());
    }
}


public void ImageCropFunction(Uri imguri) {
    try {
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(imguri, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 4);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ignored) {

    }
```

Ps: I want to keep the scropping option

Comment: You have `outputX` and `outputY` as `128`. Is the image you get back 128x128? Maybe that's the problem

Comment: @th3pat3l It gives me the same result whatever if I put 128 or 1000 or 50000.

Comment: Look at my answer below. Do that and you will still have to change that `128` to a higher number. try size like 512x512

Comment: @th3pat3l I did what you said but my uri is always null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `onActivityResult()` like this.

What you are getting back is thumbnail (128x128). You have to use that `Uri` to get the full image.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        if (selectedImage == null) {
            return;
        }

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null) {
            return;
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();


        if (picturePath != null) {
            Log.d("TAG", "picturePath " + picturePath);

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);

            if(bitmap != null) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // you can change the quality here. for dialog, you might only want 50 instead of 100..
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilderLoading = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                View mViewLoading = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_pp,null);

                final ImageView pp_customdialog_pp_IV = mViewLoading.findViewById(R.id.pp_customdialog_pp_IV);
                pp_customdialog_pp_IV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                mBuilderLoading.setView(mViewLoading);

                final AlertDialog dialogLoading = mBuilderLoading.create();
                dialogLoading.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialogLoading.show();
            } else {
                Log.e("TAG", "bitmap is null?!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My Uri selectedImage is always == null... why ?

Comment: Ah! i see why. You are sending the value of `2` with `startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 2);`. So the `if` statement has to change to `if(requestCode == 2...)`. I edited my answer. Try that

Comment: @MelvinAuvray I had chance to test out the example above. It works perfectly

Comment: I had to add some permission check before but it works, the problem is that with this method the cropping functionality doesn't exist anymore :/ How can I do to have it back ?

Comment: @MelvinAuvray You can put cropping back the way you had it but I would really not recommended that. `com.android.camera.action.CROP` in an `Intent` action only for AOSP camera. What that means is I'm sure it works on your phone but it will not work on every phone. I would personally use a library make crop functionality part of your app so you are not relying on Android phone's camera app.

Comment: Check out this library (https://github.com/biokys/cropimage) or this (https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper). They are very simple to implement

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default behavior is to return the thumbnail in the return results. so you may need to use the URI to get the full size image on return as well.